# In Gembox SpreadSheet, is there a way to detect if cell contains an error?

Tags: c#, gembox-spreadsheet

e.g. say an excel cell has a formula like:  =5/0
This displays in excel as:  #DIV/0!

In c#, the `ExcelCell.ValueType` is returned as `CellValueType.String`, and `Excell.Value` is returned as "#DIV/0!".
Is there a standard way to detect if the cell has an error ?

EDIT: clarification: is there a *general* way to detect if a cell has an error ? For example, in another Excel library (spreadsheet Gear), there is a SpreadsheetGear.ValueType of Error, which allows you to tell for any cell, if there is an error in that cell.

Comment: use if() to test for zero in the denominator.

Comment: thanks for responding. See my edit for clarification

Comment: @MoeSisko GemBox.Spreadsheet currently doesn't have `CellValueType` for errors, but we'll add it. I'll let you know when it's ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this latest bugfix version:
https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/nightlybuilds/GBS49v1115.zip

Or this latest NuGet package:
`Install-Package GemBox.Spreadsheet -Version 49.0.1115-hotfix`

Now there is a `CellValueType.Error`that you can use.